# Why does Kali Linux WSL2 not work and says Kali Linux (Rolling)

Tags: windows, kali-linux

When my computer starts it just doesn’t work, I’ll have to delete Kali and start another session. This is really the root of my problems right now. Please help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR32q.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What on earth persuaded you to try using a pen-testing OS as WSL? Why not an 'easy' unix like Ubuntu? See [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: @Tetsujin it’s really popular, and it’s good for beginners. But maybe I should switch…

Comment: It's only 'popular' since Elliot used it in Mr Robot. Elliot was a consummate hacker, hence the 'expert toolkit' appropriate to his character. Before that, only pen-testers had ever heard of it. Since, everybody wants to be seen as one of the cool kids, without beig vaguely aware of what it's actually for & how hard it is to use. It is *absolutely not* for beginners, which is why I posted the link.

Answer (score 1):

Kali (Rolling) works just fine in a proper VM (Posting from Kali V2023.2 here.

It is an operating system with little software aside from forensic and penetration software. There is little else and it is not a friendly tool.

It is not made for WSL and does not work well in WSL. I rried it and gave that up. WSL is made for running Linux commands in a Windows environment. Ubuntu works for this; Kali does not work well for this work.

> it’s good for beginners. ... Maybe I should switch.

No it is not. You need to have a reasonable understanding of Linux and terminal management of operating system.

For WSL, use Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store.

For Kali, use a Virtual Machine.

Comment: Agree with most of what you said (esp. about it not being 1st choice for beginners) but I'll point out that Kali is available from the MS store as a WSL pkg and I've installed and used it successfully here on my Win 10 daily.

Comment: I made it work in WSL but it is not for long term stability in WSL like it is in a VM.